# Does Apache Commons HttpAsyncClient support GZIP?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

This question was asked for Apache Commons HttpClient, however I'm using the **async client** `HttpAsyncClient`.

Content decompression (gzip) does not work out of the box.

I tried to configure it with:

```java
httpClientAsync = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(100)
            .setMaxConnTotal(200)
            // Enable response content encoding (gzip)
            //
            // NOTE: Does not work for some reason
            .addInterceptorLast(ResponseContentEncoding())
```

Which I copied from `HttpClientBuilder`, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are at least some bug reports related to it. Read the documentation.

Comment: It does not. Someone should come forward and contribute it to the project.

Answer (score 2):

The use of **addInterceptorLast** and **addInterceptorFirst** has no effect.
`asyncHttpClient.execute()` will create a `BasicAsyncResponseConsumer` by default.
This `BasicAsyncResponseConsumer` will copy the original `ContentDecoder` into the buffer, resulting in `DecompressingEntity.getContent()` is never called.

`org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient#execute()`

```
    public Future<HttpResponse> execute(
            final HttpHost target, final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context,
            final FutureCallback<HttpResponse> callback) {
        return execute(
                HttpAsyncMethods.create(target, request),
                HttpAsyncMethods.createConsumer(), // BasicAsyncResponseConsumer
                context, callback);
    }
```

`org.apache.http.nio.protocol.BasicAsyncResponseConsumer#onContentReceived`

```
    protected void onContentReceived(
            final ContentDecoder decoder, final IOControl ioControl) throws IOException {
        Asserts.notNull(this.buf, "Content buffer");
        this.buf.consumeContent(decoder);
    }
```

My solution is to manually call `ResponseContentEncoding.process(resp, context)` in the callback to reset the HttpEntity.

```
private static final ResponseContentEncoding responseContentEncoding = new ResponseContentEncoding();

HttpClientContext hcc = HttpClientContext.create();
asyncHttpClient.execute(bidreq, hcc, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(HttpResponse result) {
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        String content = null;
        try {
            responseContentEncoding.process(result, hcc);
            entity = result.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                content = EntityUtils.toString(entity, UTF_8);
                log.info(content);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        } finally {
            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Exception ex) {
        log.error("failed", ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() { }
});
```